# Search box + dropdown + search button

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I need to create a search bar that contains a search field, a dropdown and a search button.  I've read the material on Bootstrap 4, but I can't achieve what I need with what they show there.
Also, how would I add the "down arrows"?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. When you have a specific problem please come back and add relevant code snippet of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is something where you can start to achieve your requirement.

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

[See the results](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/193165/) in JsFiddle.